# Vue + Vuetify customize calendar component for mobile

Tags: vue.js, mobile, calendar, vuetify.js

I have [vuetify calendar component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars#calendar). This calendar (only on month type) is too big for mobile screen. 
Helper images: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG8eH.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAxYh.png)

this my code:

```
<v-layout align-space-around
          justify-center
          row wrap
          column
          fill-height>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card flat>
              <v-calendar 
                ref="calendar"
                v-model="start"
                :type="type"
                :end="end"
                :now="today"
                :value="today"
                ma-0
                locale
                @click:date="clickDate">
                  ...some calendar code here...
              </v-calendar>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

The v-card element is rendering correctly, fits for device, but calendar takes more space (for width) that his parent (v-card).

I'll be glad for some help with that.